# Tinyproxy and https requests

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, proxy

I am using a proxy to crawl a website. My proxy server is Ubuntu 14.04 with tinyproxy.
With phantomjs I was using same proxy without a problem however with regular curl I can't establish a connection. I have checked tinyproxy logs and found out:

```
CONNECT   Dec 07 23:47:43 [1139]: Connect (file descriptor 6): ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com [xx.xxx.xx.xxx]
CONNECT   Dec 07 23:47:43 [1139]: Request (file descriptor 6): CONNECT www.xxxxxxxx.com:443 HTTP/1.1
INFO      Dec 07 23:47:43 [1139]: No upstream proxy for www.xxxxxxxx.com
ERROR     Dec 07 23:49:50 [1139]: opensock: Could not establish a connection to www.xxxxxxxx.com
ERROR     Dec 07 23:49:50 [1139]: Error reading readble client_fd 6
WARNING   Dec 07 23:49:50 [1139]: Could not retrieve request entity
```

Any ideas on how am I able to connect with phantomjs to same website?
How can i use tinyproxy with https connection?
Is squid way to go in terms of proxy + https?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I've found my way around by allowing all ports in /etc/tinyproxy.conf by **removing ConnectPort** lines. At first I've tried allowing 443 80 and other required ports however it didn't worked out that way.